# Deterioration of Windows 7 after running the regsvr32 command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, installshield, regsvr32

My operating system is `Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit`.

I receive the following error message when I run `InstallShield 2010`:

> "no such interface supported"

To solve the problem, I followed these [instructions](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/37307-63-interface-supported):

> 1. Click Start . In the Search box, type CMD . At the top of the window, right-click the cmd icon and choose Run as Administrator .
> 2. At the prompt, type in FOR /R C:\ %G IN (*.dll) DO "%systemroot%\system32\regsvr32.exe" /s "%G" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now my Windows has problems, for example, some programs like Internet Explorer can not run.

How can I restore Windows to an earlier state?

Comment: Super-dangerous instructions! Basically, they tell Windows to register every DLL found in a system. volume. These kind of Barbarian-invasion-like instructions should never be followed; at least not without a whole backup in place.

Answer (score 1):

Best option would be to rollback the system to a previous state using System Restore. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `rstrui.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Choose a recent restore point (before the date when you registered the Dlls) and complete the rollback. This would rollback your registry hives, which is where Dll registration information are stored.

That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but no other solution?

Comment: Other than System Restore (or) replacing the registry hives from previous shadow copies (via recovery environment), no, there are no other options as far as I know.

Comment: Restoring from a backup works too. But I am guessing you don't have backups.

Comment: I dont have restore point.

Comment: Then the only option left is to do a [in-place upgrade](http://www.pcworld.com/article/243190/how_to_repair_a_corrupt_windows_7_installation.html) a.k.a non-destructive install of Windows 7 by running setup.exe from installation media. [Another guide](https://www.winhelp.us/non-destructive-reinstall-of-windows-7.html) for reference.